# SFML- randomly scalable sprite

Tags: c++, 2d, sfml

I'm programming a Flappy Bird clone and I have a problem with obstacles. I want to make it randomly scalable (so the gape is on random height). I don't have any idea how to do that. I've created a PNG image which looks like this:

[image: obstacle]

and tried to check how it will look when i scale it (just `sf::Sprite.setScale()`). I wasn't surprised that it looks like that:
[image: bad scaling].

So my question is how to make it looks like this:
[image]

What graphics should I make and how to code the scaling?

Comment: You could avoid the scaling just by playing with the vertical position of the pipes. If your screen is 200px tall, and your pipe is 200px, you could place it in -100px to make it look like it is scaled to the 50% of the screen.

Comment: or create a relatively small texture and stretch that and just use a another texture to render the edge in.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `sf::Sprite.setScale()`, that will make your images look "scaled" and inconsistent with the "world" that you're creating.

### Options

Other options is to create a world with "tiles", they would be more easy to handle in the future.

You can create a tile based world with the following options:

- Using the map editing tool [tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) (you will have to create maps manually).
- Making you own system to create worlds randomly with tiles (it can be hard but you will end up with a nice design).

### Can i use the assets that i've already made with a tile system?

Yes, you can. You only have to divide your assets in tiles.

Although you can always use the system you be described if you find it more easy.